# SUM until value ordered by column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with Products, Quantity and Weight. I need to find the heavier products that reach a certain value. Example:

Table:

```
Product     Qty Weight
PEN         100 50
PEN          10 30
PEN          80 20
PEN         250 20
PEN        1000 10
PAPER       150 80
PAPER      1500 20
```

Query: Find PEN that reach maximum 200 Qty ordered by Weight.

Result:

```
PEN         100 50
PEN          10 30
PEN          80 20
```

**EDIT:**
The result was that because: 100+10+80 < 200.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. What `SUM` are you looking for? Do you want the sum of the weight? Quantity?

Comment: Sorry. I want the sum of the Quantity order by Weight

Comment: `sum` of quantity is an aggregate function, returning one value, 190; order by weight is not an aggregate function, so do you want the `max(weight)`?

Comment: @Beth, Laurence already helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on SQL 2012, you can use this sort of approach for a running total:

```
Select
  Qty,
  Weight
From (
  Select
    Qty,
    Weight,
    Sum(Qty) Over(Order By Weight Desc Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) As RunningQty
  From
    Test
  Where
    Product = 'PEN'
  ) a
Where
   RunningQty <= 200
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6157b/4

Comment: It may not help, but the manual pages are http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx